# newcommand inside newcommand not working

Tags: macros, renewcommand

I often use `\newcommand` inside another `\newcommand`, and it usually works well.

But not this case:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\maketag@@@}[1]{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont{\makebox[1sp][r]{#1}}}}
\makeatother
\[1+1=2\tag{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}\]
\egroup
\[1+1=2\]

\end{document}
```

This code removes the horizontal space of the tag, so that two equations are properly aligned. I want to define this as a command, so try the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\nospacetag}[1]{%
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\maketag@@@[1]{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont{\makebox[1sp][r]{##1}}}}
    \makeatother
    #1
    }
    
\begin{document}
\nospacetag{\[1+1=2\tag{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}\]}
\[1+1=2\]

\end{document}
```

But the latex errors occur.

Comment: You have to move the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair *outside* the command definition.  But you also need to introduce a group within your command `\nospacetag` so the redefinition is limited in scope. Also, you can use `0pt` instead of `1sp`...

Comment: By the way, your need for `\nospacetag` seems unnecessary, since the `\tag` doesn't influence the horizontal placement of the math content. See [this example](https://pastebin.com/raw/nynAytfQ) and [its output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESEQP.png).

Comment: Thanks! now it works. But
1) 0pt seems to generate a new line
and 2) \tag influences the horizontal placement when the content in it is long enough